# MP3 cover photo export as JPG format

Tags: php, id3

I have a code to preview cover photo from mp3 file. it show the cover photo but i want to export the image as  .jpg format how to do that? here is my code

```
require_once('getid3.php');

$getID3 = new getID3;
#$getID3->option_tag_id3v2 = true;
$getID3->analyze("Daayre.mp3");

if (isset($getID3->info['id3v2']['APIC'][0]['data'])) {
    $cover = $getID3->info['id3v2']['APIC'][0]['data'];
} elseif (isset($getID3->info['id3v2']['PIC'][0]['data'])) {
    $cover = $getID3->info['id3v2']['PIC'][0]['data'];
} else {
    $cover = null;
}

if (isset($getID3->info['id3v2']['APIC'][0]['image_mime'])) {
    $mimetype = $getID3->info['id3v2']['APIC'][0]['image_mime'];
} else {
    $mimetype = 'image/jpeg'; // or null; depends on your needs
}

if (!is_null($cover)) {
    header("Content-Type: ".$mimetype);
    if (isset($getID3->info['id3v2']['APIC'][0]['image_bytes'])) {
        header("Content-Length: ".$getID3->info['id3v2']['APIC'][0]['image_bytes']);
    }

    echo($cover);
}
```

here if i write `<img src="<?php echo $cover; ?>"/>` then it show the picture.
i want to export the picture.
how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

What is stored inside of `$cover`? It seems as if you should be able to just write `$cover` to a file. Try `file_put_contents`, example:

```
//If $cover is not a stream or string of data, you may need to make it one.
//For example, using fopen or another method depending on what $cover is
$filename = "somefilename.jpg";
file_put_contents($filename, $cover);
```

More info on `file_put_contents` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php). It also depends on what you mean by "export". Are you wanting to send the file to the user or just store the file on your computer/server?

Comment: i want to store it as jpg file in local directry

Comment: Thanks @Swister . If this answer was the correct one and helped you, would you mind accepting it as the answer? Thanks!